# How do I install hexen2/Hammer of Thyrion?

Tags: software-installation

I have downloaded this file and can't open it.

I haven't much experience in Linux but I tried several programs; Software-Center, synaptic, Archive manager, and gedit which was set as default and none of the will open it.

The file I'm trying to install is `hexen2-installer-1.5.6-linux.run`, which is available for download from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/uhexen2/files/Hammer%20of%20Thyrion/) under Linux-installer.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most likely as a result of it being downloaded it won't have the correct file permissions, first you'll need to make it executable:

```
chmod u+x hexen2-installer-1.5.6-linux.run
```

Then simply execute the file:

```
./hexen2-installer-1.5.6-linux.run
```

Comment: $sudo user@host:~$ chmod +x hexen2-installer-1.5.6-linux.run = command not found

Comment: I have edited to clarify for you, you didn't need the "user@host~$" section, this was merely the prompt

Comment: "chmod +x...etc..."                                            cannot access `hexen2-installer-1.5.6-linux.run': No such file or directory

Comment: You need to first change to the directory that contains the file...

Comment: How to change Directory?

Comment: `cd` <path to where you downloaded it>, if you downloaded it to the default location you should be able to get there with `cd ~/Downloads`

Comment: @kalina this works fine, thanks: however: The setup program seems to have failed on x86_64/unknown

:Fatal error, no tech support email configured in this setup

Comment: This error is actually [discussed on the project page on SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/p/uhexen2/discussion/425206/thread/6abb0e5e/) - a solution suggested here is to install alien and download the .rpm version (from the link you originally used) and convert it to a .deb and install it that way using dpkg. [This page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RPM/AlienHowto) will tell you how to install alien and use it to convert a rpm file...

Answer (score 3):

I will give you the GUI way;

- Select that file with right click
- Choose "Properties" from the menu
- Select the "Permissions" tab
- Check "Allow executing as a program"

[image]

Click on "Close" and double click the file to run it.